# How to pass-by-value in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, parameter-passing

I'm doing a programming contest with Kotlin, and there are lots of times when I need parameter is pass-by-value, how do I do that?

```
fun main() {
    val p = Person(18)
    println(p.age) // 18
    changeAge(p)
    println(p.age) // 21, but I want it still 18

}

data class Person(var age: Int)

fun changeAge(p: Person) {
    p.age = 21
}
```

Comment: Which value do you want to pass? (Person or Int?) `p` still are the Person which you passed.

Comment: I want to pass a copy of `Person` to `changeAge`. Then after `changeAge` done, `p.age` still equals 18.

Comment: for data classes you can use copy method `changeAge(p.copy())`

Comment: your code is working check : https://pl.kotl.in/x31YotRAD

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Ok there's an idea.

Comment: @RahulKhatri What do you mean? I don't want it print 32 tho.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the copy() method.

in your code it would be something like this

```
changeAge(p.copy(age=99))
```